# Create one review per commit with arcanist

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

Whenever I'm writing code, I usually do small improvements in code not related to my current task, and let those changes in separate independent commits.

When I send my code to review, with `arc diff`, arcanist is creating a single review with all commits (as if they were squashed), is it possible to create multiple reviews (one per commit)?

PS: this is my .arcconfig

```
{
  "phabricator.uri" : "http://192.168.0.1/",
  "history.immutable" : true
}
```

Comment: I don't know arcanist, but it would be common for review tools to create a single review containing all commits on the current branch ahead of the target-branch. When making unrelated changes, could you quickly switch-out to a clean branch and make them there?  You would need to repeat that on your current branch if you want to work with those changes in-place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can force arcanist to create a new diff with `arc diff --create`.
See `arc help diff` for more details

Comment: I believe that this will create one diff/review for all commits, which will all get squashed when the diff is landed. It's not what the question is asking for.